# Stop installation of the application without ble availability iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on an application that involves use of bluetooth-le.
As BLE is only available in iOS7 and from iPhone 4s on-words.

I have set that app is only available for iOS7.
And hardware requirement to BLE but application can be downloaded on iPhone 4 as well which does not have BLE.

I am looking for a way to make my app unavailable for iPhone4 as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that BLE is not only available on iOS7. New mechanism appeared in iOS6 and iOS7, but it existed already on iOS5.

Comment: the problem i am facing the devices that does not have ble capabilities should not be able to download this app

Comment: Well, normally, if you use `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` and `bluetooth-le` according to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW10, that should be enough.

Comment: even after setting that app gets installed on iPhone4 through XCode. How to make sure that app cannot be downloaded from App-Store??

Comment: After setting that we are get a BLE related message when installed through xcode, but if we build a ipa host it on a server and then install it on iPhone4 it get installed. How to make sure that app cannot be downloaded from App-Store??

Answer (score 0):

App Store does not have a way to limit by device when you upload. It is done via info.plist. The App Store process actually goes through your ipa, grabs the info.plist file and does a whole bunch of other stuff with the binary anyway.

First rule: Apple does what Apple wants to do. I would like to say 'no - Apple cannot reject your app due to not supporting features you said you wouldn't support', but truth is I can't. The closest I can do is say 'no - Apple should not reject your app...'

Not sure exactly how to edit info.plist, but the Apple iOS reference library has all the info. Something like this: (1) Generate your ipa (2) Rename it to .zip and unzip it (3) find the info.plist file and edit it (4) zip it back up and rename. From memory I think people have had problems with step 4 and there is another way to do it on the Mac with a utility.

To my knowledge:

iPhone4 is the only device with a camera flash
iPod Touch does not support telephony
iPhone 1st gen does not have GPS
iPhone3GS supports OpenGLES2.0 (the 3G only supports 1.1) and has a magnetometer (3G does not)
iPad does not have a still camera

So the logic for each build would be something like:

iPad: still-camera MUST BE false
iPhone4: camera-flash MUST BE true
iPhone3GS: magnetometer MUST BE true, AND telephony MUST BE true, AND camera-flash MUST BE false
iPhone3G: telephony MUST BE true, AND magnetometer MUST BE false, AND gpd MUST BE true
iPhone: telephony MUST BE true, AND gps MUST BE false
iPod Touch: telephony MUST BE false

Comment: After setting that we are get a BLE related message when installed through xcode, but if we build a ipa host it on a server and then install it on iPhone4 it get installed. How to make sure that app cannot be downloaded from App-Store??